# show image in tooltips properties in excel from olap cube

Tags: excel, ssas, olap

I have a olap cube and can send along tooltip data. When the end-user (using excel) is quering against the data i want it to be possible for him/her to show/hide either a tooltip or include in report a picture.

I can send the URL to the picture, but then I want exel to show it as a picture instead of an URL.

Is this possible?